# regarding a method definition in a class

Tags: java

I have a question regarding the class definition in Java. With respect to the following code segment, after the `if` switch already verifies that `h is an instance of Animal`, why we still need to add the line of `Animal ob = (Animal) h`?  In addition, why the second coding segment is wrong? I know it should come from the line of `public boolean equals (Animal h)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Paste code as text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) takes an object of type `Object`, so the second example is wrong because it takes an `Animal` object instead. In the first one, the cast is because the variable has type `Object`, even though it actually is an instance of the `Animal` type, so it needs to be cast to be assigned to a variable of type `Animal`.

Comment: Technically wrong, since it is possible to overload `.equals()` as shown in the code.

Comment: By "wrong", I meant that it probably isn't what he meant. I actually thought about that wording, and I don't think explaining that would make my answer more helpful to OP.

Comment: The problem is that there's nothing wrong with overloading `.equals()` except for the fact that it makes it horribly hard to maintain and debug when using inheritance.

Comment: That isn't something wrong with it? I understand that the code will compile, but, again, that probably isn't what OP meant.

Comment: But what if he actually did want to overload `.equals()`? If done correctly, it could be just what he needs. I don't think it's a fair assumption to make when OP hasn't made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You have to check with `instanceof` because the received `Object h` could be an instance of any class, since in Java all classes automatically inherit from the `Object` class.

For example, it could be a `Fruit`. And if it's a `Fruit`, it's not an `Animal`. If you attempted to cast it to `Animal` anyways, a `ClassCastException` would be thrown.

This is why, before casting the received `Object h` to `Animal`, it is first checked that `h` is actually an instance of the `Animal` class. If `(h instanceof Animal)` evaluates to `false`, it means that `h` is not an `Animal`, so the cast is not performed and no `ClassCastException` is thrown.

The cast is necessary to tell the compiler that `h` is actually an instance of the `Animal` class (all the compiler knows so far is that `h` is an instance of the `Object` class, because that's the type of the argument of the method). This way, you can access to `h`'s data  via the members of the `Animal` class.

2 - The second method is technically correct, but both the `instanceof` checking and the cast are not necessary, since the received `Animal h` can't help being an `Animal`. So, why checking what is obvious? If the method gets executed, it's because it was invoked with an argument whose static type was already `Animal`. So all you'd need to do before accessing `h`'s fields, is checking if `h` is not `null`.